# Key scientific publications reporting non-normal GLMMs in marine biology

Tags: r, glmm, reporting

I developed Poisson and Binomial GLMMs following the steps described in the excellent book from Zuur et al. (2009) *[Mixed Effects Models and Extensions in Ecology with R](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441927646)* and I'm now ready to include my results into manuscripts to be submitted for publication. However, I'm struggling to find published studies in marine biology using non-normal GLMMs to use as a guideline to write my Methods and Results sections.

**What scientific publications would be good guidelines as to how to report non-normal GLMMs in the field of marine biology?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is an excerpt from chapter 13 of [Fox, Negrete-Yankelevich, and Sosa 2015](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/ecological-statistics-9780199672554?cc=ca&lang=en&) (excerpt on [Google Books](https://books.google.ca/books?id=PuZcBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA309&dq=fox+sosa+bolker&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=symbionts%20analysis&f=false)) describing my (somewhat informed :-) ) opinions on reporting GLMM results. The particular example excerpted here is using data from [McKeon et al. 2012](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00442-012-2275-2) "Multiple defender effects: synergistic coral defense by mutualist crustaceans" (*Oecologia*, so not a marine biology *journal*, but at least a marine biology topic ...)  More generally, a [Google Scholar search on "lme4 glmer marine biology"](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=lme4+glmer+marine+biology&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5) should get you some reasonable examples ...

> Graphical summaries of statistical analyses that display the model coefficients and their uncertainty, or that overlay model predictions and their uncertainties on the original data, are important (Gelman et al. 2002). However, you also need to summarize the results in words. This summary should include the magnitudes and confidence intervals of the fixed effects; the magnitude of the among-group variation for each random effect, whether it is of primary interest or not; and possibly the confidence intervals of the among-group variation (if the random effects are included because they are part of the design, you should not test the null hypothesis that they are zero). If you are interested in the partitioning of variance across levels, report among-group variation as random-effect variances, or proportions of variance (see the grouse tick example below). If you are more interested in the fixed effects, report among-group variation as random-effect standard deviations, as these are directly comparable to the corresponding fixed effects. The following are sample reports for the four worked examples; appendix 13A shows the technical details of deriving these results. The results from all the combinations of estimation and inference methods in this chapter are summarized in Figure 13.3.
>
> **Coral symbionts:** For the analysis done here (logit link, one-way comparison of crab/shrimp/both to control) we could quote either the fixed-effect parameter estimates (clarifying to the reader that these are differences between treatments and the baseline control treatment, on the logit or log-odds scale), or the changes in predation probability from one group to another. Taking the first approach: “Crab and shrimp treatments had similar effects (–3.8 log-odds decrease in predation probability for crab, –4.4 for shrimp); the dual-symbiont treatment had an even larger effect (–5.5 units), but although the presence of any symbiont caused a significant drop in predation probability relative to the control (Wald p-value 0.0013; parametric bootstrap p-value < 0.003), none of the symbiont treatments differed significantly from each other (likelihood ratio test p = 0.27, parametric bootstrap test (N = 220) p = 0.23); in particular, two symbionts
>   did not have significantly greater protective effects than one (Wald and PB p-values both ≈ 0.15). The among-block standard deviation in log-odds of predation was 3.4, nearly as large as the symbiont effect.” (McKeon et al. (2012) present slightly different conclusions based on a model with a log rather than a logit link.) Alternately, one could quote the predicted predation probabilities for each group, which might be more understandable for an ecological audience.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer @Ben Bolker, it's much appreciated to have the opinion of someone "somewhat" informed on reporting GLMMs results! The book excerpt and the McKeon et al. 2012 paper will be valuable to me and other marine biologists trying to find the best way to describe and present GLMMs results.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would provide the following paper which I find is reporting GLMM results quite well in a marine biology context:

Laurich et al. (2015) *[Temporal variation in chemoautotrophic symbiont abundance
in the thyasirid bivalve Thyasira cf. gouldi](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00227-015-2727-4)*.